# Coefficient plot - Increase gap between rows and alternative background colors in rows

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have created this coefficient plot. However, I cannot increase the gap between rows. I also like to add an alternative background colour of row (like row-wise grey then white then grey ) to make it easier for the reader to read the plot. Would you please support improving its visualization?

[image: my plot is here]

I used the following code to create this plot.

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  SubgroupH=c('Age',NA,NA,NA,NA,'Marital or Union Status',NA,NA, NA, 'Place of Residence', NA, NA, 'Education', NA, NA, NA, NA,'Occupation', NA, NA, NA, NA, 'Wealth', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'Reading newspaper or magazine', NA, NA, NA, 'Frequency of watching television', NA, NA, NA, 'Frequency of  listening radio', NA, NA, NA ),
  Subgroup=c(NA,'15-19','20-29','30-39','40-49', NA, 'Currently Married or Union', 'Never Married or Union','Formally Married or Union', NA, 'Rural', 'Urban', NA, 'Higher', 'Secondary', 'Primary', 'No eduction', NA, 'Not working', 'Professional/technical/managerial/services', 'Agriculture', 'Skilled/unskilled manual', NA, 'Poorest', 'Poorer', 'Middle','Richer', 'Richest',  NA, 'Not at all', 'Less than once a week', 'At least once a week', NA, 'Not at all', 'Less than once a week', 'At least once a week', NA, 'Not at all', 'Less than once a week', 'At least once a week'),
  AdjustedOR=c(NA,1,'2.76 (2.49-3.07)','3.68 (3.26-4.15)','4.61 (4.06-5.23)',NA,1,'1.03 (0.94-1.13)', '1.26 (1.04-1.54)', NA, 1,'1.12 (1.04-1.21)', NA, 1, '1.42 (1.30-1.56)', '2.09 (1.85-2.36)', '2.20 (1.93-2.49)', NA, 1, '1.39 (1.25-1.54)', '1.37 (1.24-1.51)', '1.55 (1.39-1.72)', NA, 1, '0.91 (0.84-0.99)', '0.77 (0.71-0.84)', '0.72 (0.65-0.79)', '0.61 (0.54-0.69)', NA, 1, '1 (0.91-1.10)', '0.92 (0.85-0.998)', NA, 1, '1.19 (1.07-1.31)', '1.29 (1.19-1.40)', NA, 1, '1.19 (1.09-1.30)', '1.13 (1.05-1.21)'),
  OddsRatio=c(NA,1,2.76,3.68,4.61, NA,1,1.03, 1.26, NA, 1,1.12, NA, 1, 1.42, 2.09, 2.20, NA, 1, 1.39, 1.37, 1.55, NA, 1, 0.91, 0.77, 0.78, 0.61 , NA, 1, 1,0.92, NA, 1,1.19,1.29, NA, 1, 1.19, 1.13),
  ORLower=c(NA,NA,2.49,3.26,4.06,NA,NA,0.94, 1.04, NA, NA,1.04, NA, NA, 1.30,1.85, 1.93, NA, NA,1.25, 1.24, 1.39, NA, NA, 0.84, 0.71, 0.65, 0.54, NA, NA, 0.91, 0.85, NA, NA, 1.07, 1.19, NA, NA,1.09, 1.05),
  ORUpper=c(NA,NA,3.07,4.15,5.23,NA,NA,1.13, 1.54, NA, NA,1.21, NA, NA, 1.56, 2.36, 2.49, NA, NA, 1.54, 1.51,1.72, NA, NA, 0.99, 0.84, 0.79, 0.69, NA, NA, 1.10, 0.998, NA, NA, 1.31, 1.40, NA, NA, 1.30,1.21),
  Pvalue=c(NA,NA,'< 0.001','< 0.001','< 0.001', NA,NA, 0.518, 0.021, NA, NA, 0.003, NA, NA, '< 0.001', '< 0.001', '< 0.001', NA, NA, '< 0.001', '< 0.001', '< 0.001', NA, NA, 0.029, '< 0.001','< 0.001','< 0.001', NA, NA, 0.993, 0.045, NA, NA, '< 0.001','< 0.001',NA, NA, '< 0.001', 0.002),  
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE )

#png('temp.png', width=8, height=4, units='in', res=400)

rowseq <- seq(nrow(mydf),1)
par(mai=c(0.7,0,0,0))
plot(mydf$OddsRatio, rowseq, pch=15,
     xlim=c(-0.8,6.2), ylim=c(0,42),
     xlab='', ylab='', yaxt='n', xaxt='n',
     bty='n')
axis(1, seq(0.5, 5,by=0.5), cex.axis=1)

segments(1,-1,1,40.20, lty=3, )
segments(mydf$ORLower, rowseq, mydf$ORUpper, rowseq)

mtext('Adjusted Odds Ratio (95% CI)', 1, line=2, at=1.2, cex=1, font=2)

text(-1,42, "Factors", cex=1.4, font=2, pos=4)
t1h <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$SubgroupH), mydf$SubgroupH, '')
text(-1,rowseq, t1h, cex=1.3, pos=4, font=2)
t1 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Subgroup), mydf$Subgroup, '')
text(-0.98,rowseq, t1, cex=1.3, pos=4)

text(4.6,42, "Adjusted Odds Ratio (95% CI)", cex=1.4, font=2, pos=4)
t2 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$AdjustedOR), format(mydf$AdjustedOR,big.mark=","), '')
text(6, rowseq, t2, cex=1.3, pos=2)

text(6,42, "P-value", cex=1.4, font=2, pos=4)
t4 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Pvalue), mydf$Pvalue, '')
text(6,rowseq, t4, cex=1.3, pos=4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could play with flexible and different `cex` and adjust with the `png` parameters. This looks already better. For line-by-line gray shading we can simply use `abline` with modulo 2.

```
cex11 <- 1
cex12 <- 1.2
cex42 <- cex41 <- cex23 <- cex22 <- cex21 <- 1.3


png('temp.png', width=23, height=12, units='in', res=400)

par(mai=c(0.7, 0, 0, 0))

rowseq <- seq(nrow(mydf), 1)
plot(mydf$OddsRatio, rowseq, xlim=c(-0.8, 6.2), ylim=c(0, 42), 
     xlab='', ylab='', yaxt='n', xaxt='n', bty='n')
abline(h=rowseq[rowseq %% 2 != 0], lwd=25, col='grey90')   ## grey shading
points(mydf$OddsRatio, rowseq, pch=15)
axis(1, seq(0.5, 5, by=0.5), cex.axis=cex11)
segments(1, -1, 1, 40.20, lty=3, )
segments(mydf$ORLower, rowseq, mydf$ORUpper, rowseq)
mtext('Adjusted Odds Ratio (95% CI)', 1, line=2, at=1.2, cex=cex12, font=2)
text(-1, 42, "Factors", cex=cex21, font=2, pos=4)
t1h <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$SubgroupH), mydf$SubgroupH, '')
text(-1, rowseq, t1h, cex=cex22, pos=4, font=2)
t1 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Subgroup), mydf$Subgroup, '')
text(-0.98, rowseq, t1, cex=cex23, pos=4)
text(4.6, 42, "Adjusted Odds Ratio (95% CI)", cex=cex41, font=2, pos=4)
t2 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$AdjustedOR), format(mydf$AdjustedOR, big.mark=", "), '')
text(6, rowseq, t2, cex=cex42, pos=2)
text(6, 42, "P-value", cex=cex41, font=2, pos=4)
t4 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Pvalue), mydf$Pvalue, '')
text(6, rowseq, t4, cex=cex41, pos=4)

dev.off()
```

[image]

### However,

it might be more convenient to expand the `mar`gins and use `mtext` instead of `text`. The code parts could also be better organized to avoid confusion. For the names of text parameters, use numbers according to their plot margin which are numbered according to their quadrant (1=bottom, 2=left, 3=top, 4=right). So try this:

```
## parameters
rowseq <- rev(seq_len(dim(mydf)[1]))
rg <- range(mydf[c('ORLower', 'ORUpper')], na.rm=TRUE)

t2h <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$SubgroupH), mydf$SubgroupH, '')
t2 <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Subgroup), mydf$Subgroup, '')
t4or <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$AdjustedOR), format(mydf$AdjustedOR, big.mark=", "), '')
t4p <- ifelse(!is.na(mydf$Pvalue), mydf$Pvalue, '')

cexh1 <- 1.3
cexh2 <- 1.2
cext <- 1.1
```

```
## plot
png('temp.png', width=18, height=12, units='in', res=400)

op <- par(mar=c(5, 18.5, 4, 15)+.1)

plot(mydf$OddsRatio, rowseq, type='n', xlim=rg, axes=FALSE, xlab='', ylab='')
## content
abline(h=rowseq[rowseq %% 2 == 0], lwd=20, col='grey95', xpd=TRUE)  ## grey shades
points(mydf$OddsRatio, rowseq, pch=15)
segments(1, 0, 1, max(rowseq)*1.025, lty=3)
segments(mydf$ORLower, rowseq, mydf$ORUpper, rowseq)
## margin 1
axis(1, seq(0.5, 5, by=0.5), cex.axis=cex11)
mtext('Adjusted Odds Ratio (95% CI)', 1, line=2.5, at=1.2, cex=cexh1, font=2)
## margin 2
mtext("Factors", 2, 17.5, at=max(rowseq)*1.03, las=2, adj=0, font=2, cex=cexh1)
mtext(t2h, 2, 17.5, at=rowseq, las=2, adj=0, font=2, cex=cexh2)
mtext(t2, 2, 17, at=rowseq, las=2, adj=0, cex=cext)
## margin 4
mtext("Adjusted Odds Ratio (95% CI)", 4, 7, at=max(rowseq)*1.03, las=2, adj=1,
      font=2, cex=cexh1)
mtext(t4or, 4, 7, at=rowseq, las=2, adj=1, cex=cext)
mtext("P-value", 4, 12, at=max(rowseq)*1.03, las=2, adj=1, font=2, cex=cexh1)
mtext(t4p, 4, 12, at=rowseq, las=2, adj=1, cex=cext)

par(op)

dev.off()
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
mydf <- structure(list(SubgroupH = c("Age", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Marital or Union Status", 
NA, NA, NA, "Place of Residence", NA, NA, "Education", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "Occupation", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Wealth", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Reading newspaper or magazine", NA, NA, NA, "Frequency of watching television", 
NA, NA, NA, "Frequency of  listening radio", NA, NA, NA), Subgroup = c(NA, 
"15-19", "20-29", "30-39", "40-49", NA, "Currently Married or Union", 
"Never Married or Union", "Formally Married or Union", NA, "Rural", 
"Urban", NA, "Higher", "Secondary", "Primary", "No eduction", 
NA, "Not working", "Professional/technical/managerial/services", 
"Agriculture", "Skilled/unskilled manual", NA, "Poorest", "Poorer", 
"Middle", "Richer", "Richest", NA, "Not at all", "Less than once a week", 
"At least once a week", NA, "Not at all", "Less than once a week", 
"At least once a week", NA, "Not at all", "Less than once a week", 
"At least once a week"), AdjustedOR = c(NA, "1", "2.76 (2.49-3.07)", 
"3.68 (3.26-4.15)", "4.61 (4.06-5.23)", NA, "1", "1.03 (0.94-1.13)", 
"1.26 (1.04-1.54)", NA, "1", "1.12 (1.04-1.21)", NA, "1", "1.42 (1.30-1.56)", 
"2.09 (1.85-2.36)", "2.20 (1.93-2.49)", NA, "1", "1.39 (1.25-1.54)", 
"1.37 (1.24-1.51)", "1.55 (1.39-1.72)", NA, "1", "0.91 (0.84-0.99)", 
"0.77 (0.71-0.84)", "0.72 (0.65-0.79)", "0.61 (0.54-0.69)", NA, 
"1", "1 (0.91-1.10)", "0.92 (0.85-0.998)", NA, "1", "1.19 (1.07-1.31)", 
"1.29 (1.19-1.40)", NA, "1", "1.19 (1.09-1.30)", "1.13 (1.05-1.21)"
), OddsRatio = c(NA, 1, 2.76, 3.68, 4.61, NA, 1, 1.03, 1.26, 
NA, 1, 1.12, NA, 1, 1.42, 2.09, 2.2, NA, 1, 1.39, 1.37, 1.55, 
NA, 1, 0.91, 0.77, 0.78, 0.61, NA, 1, 1, 0.92, NA, 1, 1.19, 1.29, 
NA, 1, 1.19, 1.13), ORLower = c(NA, NA, 2.49, 3.26, 4.06, NA, 
NA, 0.94, 1.04, NA, NA, 1.04, NA, NA, 1.3, 1.85, 1.93, NA, NA, 
1.25, 1.24, 1.39, NA, NA, 0.84, 0.71, 0.65, 0.54, NA, NA, 0.91, 
0.85, NA, NA, 1.07, 1.19, NA, NA, 1.09, 1.05), ORUpper = c(NA, 
NA, 3.07, 4.15, 5.23, NA, NA, 1.13, 1.54, NA, NA, 1.21, NA, NA, 
1.56, 2.36, 2.49, NA, NA, 1.54, 1.51, 1.72, NA, NA, 0.99, 0.84, 
0.79, 0.69, NA, NA, 1.1, 0.998, NA, NA, 1.31, 1.4, NA, NA, 1.3, 
1.21), Pvalue = c(NA, NA, "< 0.001", "< 0.001", "< 0.001", NA, 
NA, "0.518", "0.021", NA, NA, "0.003", NA, NA, "< 0.001", "< 0.001", 
"< 0.001", NA, NA, "< 0.001", "< 0.001", "< 0.001", NA, NA, "0.029", 
"< 0.001", "< 0.001", "< 0.001", NA, NA, "0.993", "0.045", NA, 
NA, "< 0.001", "< 0.001", NA, NA, "< 0.001", "0.002")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))
```

Comment: Thank you Jay.sf. It works. However, it reduces the font size of texts. Would you please share how can it be done with keeping standard font size?

Comment: @SharifAsad As said, play with different `cex` and `png` parameters, see update.